# Defaultly show the placeholder in last position in select drop down in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

If am passing the json data and display it in dropdown its work fine by using angularjs and html5.
But when am get the data from the services and display in select drop down. The placeholder is listed down in the last position with black color and other datas from the services on the top of place holder. Then the first data is in greyed color. Can you please help me regarding this issue.

json data:

```
{
   key: "filterAssignedWorkGroupName",
   type: "select",
   label: "workgroup"
   placeholder: "select the workgroupname",
   option: []
}
```

in angularjs am using

```
 <option ng-if="option.placeholder" value=""
         selected>{{option.placeholder}}</option>
```

Comment: can you give plnkr or fiddle? It will give better idea.

Comment: @dhavalcengg Sorry am using this in office. i cannot able to copy the code and paste it. so only i post the details only. please help me regarding this issue

Comment: may be because you are using ng-if.. not sure. If you remove ng-if, what is your output?

Comment: @dhavalcengg I tried that also bu the output remains same. even tried ng-init instead of

Comment: prediction is hard.. need some code, man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with `ng-if` - `ng-if` causes Angular to add/remove the element from the DOM, and so (my guess) the `<option>` element is added last when the data driving `ng-if` comes from an asynchronous operation.

The solution is to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" 
        ng-options="option for option in option.option">
   <option ng-show="option.placeholder" value="">{{option.placeholder}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kofxFy3GgZOzWAm1TOib?p=preview) that illustrates the differences

Comment: Can you please show me the demo same as it is push the option value dynamically. Here you are using option array in js. in my code it coming from backend and push it in option array

Comment: The demo has the async option simulated with `$timeout`. It would behave exactly like the data coming from the backend, but just in case I added that as well.

Comment: @sandysuresh88, added it now.

Comment: no am askong first option is must be empty and it dynamically adding by using push array method.???pls demo it

Comment: I don't understand. You have the data, but not yet the "placeholder" option? What's the sequence of how you are getting the data?

Comment: in the initial stage option is like option : []; The some data is pushed in the option array

Comment: Ok, updated the plunker - but this has little to do with you original issue.